# Want text to append 1 letter at a time (or in chunks) d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Ok, I am playing with the idea of appending text in 1 by 1 one chunks (or grouped by words and appending on the screen).

I am struggling to get individual data elements to append, though. Any thoughts?

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yh7k4tbt/2/

```
function textAppend() {

  var width = 960,
    height = 500;

  var svg = d3.select('#flex-title').append('svg')
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(32," + (height / 2) + ")");

  var data = 'Welcome to the Jungle!'.split(' ');

  console.log('data is: ', data);

  var step = 0,
  dataToPlot = [];

  var textAdd = setInterval(
  function(){
    dataToPlot.push(data[step]);
    step += 1;
    console.log('step is: ', step);
    // stop once all data is plotted
      if (step > data.length) {
      clearInterval(textAdd);
    } else {
    update();
    } 

  }
  ,1000);

  function update() {
    var t = d3.transition()
        .duration(750);

    // JOIN new data with old elements.
    var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(data);

    // ENTER new elements present in new data.
    text.enter().append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("y", -60)
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * 64; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
        .style('fill', 'black')
        .text(function(d) {console.log('d is :', d); return d; })
        .transition(t)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);
  }

};

textAppend();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one core mistake and one minor mistake:

Core mistake: It should be `.data(dataToPlot);`  not `.data(data);`

Minor mistake is the way you implemented the counting function. This is more correct and concise:

```
var textAdd = setInterval(
  function() {
    // stop once all data is plotted
    if (step >= data.length) {
      clearInterval(textAdd);
      return;
    }

    dataToPlot.push(data[step]);
    console.log('step is: ', step);
    update();
    step++;
  }
,1000);
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yh7k4tbt/3/

Comment: I just figured it out as soon as I saw this, too. But thanks, that looks a lot better.